# angularjs table with multiple arrays using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, html-table

I am trying to plot a table with nested rows inside each column:

Set1  element1  element2 element3 element4 element5 ...element10(array1)
              element1  element2 element3 element4 element5 ...element10(array2)   
              
      element1  element2 element3 element4 element5 ...element10(array3)
              
      element1  element2 element3 element4 element5 ...element10(array4)
              
      element1  element2 element3 element4 element5 ...element10(array5)

Set2 element11  element12 element13 element14 element15 ...element20(array1)
              
     element11  element12 element13 element14 element15 ...element20(array2)
               
              element11  element12 element13 element14 element15 ...element20(array3)
              
     element11  element12 element13 element14 element15 ...element20(array4)
              
     element11  element12 element13 element14 element15 ...element20(array5)

.
.
.
SetN

Can someone help to implement this with ng-repeat having only 10 entries of each array in single set.

I tried to write this code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="info" colspan="3">Combo</th>
      <th class="info" colspan="10">Repititions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr border="1 px solid black">
      <th class="info" colspan="3">{{repitition_length.length}} Shots</th>
      <th class="info">1</th>
      <th class="info">2</th>
      <th class="info">3</th>
      <th class="info">4</th>
      <th class="info">5</th>
      <th class="info">6</th>
      <th class="info">7</th>
      <th class="info">8</th>
      <th class="info">9</th>
      <th class="info">10</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Set {{i+1}}</td>
      <td>
        <tr ng-repeat="i in array" ng-init="index = i*10">
          <td ng-repeat="one in color_with_mushin.slice(index,index+10)" bgcolor={{one.color}}>{{one.value}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="i in array" ng-init="index = i*10">
          <td ng-repeat="one in color_with_quite_eye_percentage.slice(index,index+10)" bgcolor={{one.color}}>
            {{one.value}}
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="i in array" ng-init="index = i*10">
          <td ng-repeat="one in color_with_quite_eye_counter.slice(index,index+10)" bgcolor={{one.color}}>
            {{one.value}}
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="i in array" ng-init="index = i*10">
          <td ng-repeat="one in color_with_rep_score.slice(index,index+10)" bgcolor={{one.color}}>{{one.value}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="i in array" ng-init="index = i*10">
          <td ng-repeat="one in color_with_grand_total.slice(index,index+10)" bgcolor={{one.color}}>{{one.value}}</td>
        </tr>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In controller I have defined $scode.index and $scope.array:

```
$scope.index = 0;
$scope.array = [];
for(var i=0; i<$scope.color_with_mushin.length/10;i++)                                                           
{
  $scope.array.push(i);
}
```

What I am getting as output is:

What I want is first row with ten entries of each array then in second row next ten entries of all arrays and so on.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your angular code to see what's going wrong?

Comment: @rrd I have edited the question can you please suggest whats wrong with the code I am stucked from a very long time.

Comment: Your table code needs a bit of work as you have a <tr> inside a <td>, but will have a closer look when i get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using slice, I'm assuming your data is stored in some consecutive arrays.

I prefer using the data object directly so I'll go for this approach.

```
$scope.sets = [];

$scope.color_with_mushin.forEach(function(item, i) {
    var set = Math.floor(i/10);

    if (!$scope.sets[set]) {
        $scope.sets[set] = new Array(5);
    }

    item.type = "color_with_mushin";
    $scope.sets[set][0].push(item);
});

// repeat for each data array, or you can refactor the code and make use of a predefined source array like

var sources = ["color_with_mushin", "color_with_quite_eye_percentage", ...]

<div ng-repeat="set in sets">
    <div>Set {{$index + 1}}</div>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in set">
            <td ng-repeat="data in row" bgcolor={{data.color}}>{{data.value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```